# React material UI open login dialog if token expired

Tags: reactjs

I am using react material UI. I am frequently checking if token is expired using setInternval() and if its expire than login dialog should be open and setInterval should be cleared using clearInterval(). Below is my code but I am getting warning as `Warning: setState(...): Can only update a mounted or mounting component. This usually means you called setState() on an unmounted component. This is a no-op.` and not able to achieve the required result.

App.js

```
import AuthService from './includes/AuthService.js';
class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
      super(props);    
      this.Auth = new AuthService();
  }

  componentDidMount(){
      setInterval(() => {this.Auth.checkToken()}, 10000);
  }
}
```

AuthService.js

```
class AuthService extends React.Component{
   constructor(props) {
     super(props);
     this.state = {email: '', password : '', loginOpen : false};
   }

   checkToken() {
     console.log("token checked");      
     if (decode(localStorage.getItem('jwtToken')).exp < Date.now() / 1000) {
         this.setState({loginOpen : true}, () => {
            console.log('state updated');
            console.log(this.state.loginOpen);
            clearInterval();
        });
     }
    }

   render(){
  const { onRequestClose } = this.props;
    const actions = [
            <FlatButton
              label="Close"
              primary={true}
              onClick={this.handleClose}
            />,

          ];
  return (

          <MuiThemeProvider>
  <Dialog title="Result Details"
      actions={actions}
      modal={false}
      open={this.state.loginOpen}
      onRequestClose={this.handleClose}
      autoScrollBodyContent={true}
    >
  </Dialog>
  </MuiThemeProvider>
}
```

Comment: The problem is that the application can call multiple API requests at once and thus expire the token for all of them.

Comment: There's no multiple API request. I am just checking expiry time of JWT that is stored in localstorage.

Comment: I'm saying that most applications are made with many requests and if the token expires, all of them will fail together.

Comment: Yes. This is what token is meant for and has expire time.

Answer (score 0):

`loginOpen` and `checkToken()` look like something that can be moved up to `App` component, and be passed to `AuthService` as props.

Alternatively, you can simply move down and call `checkToken()` on `componentDidMount()` function of `AuthService`.

Like this:

```js
class AuthService extends React.Component{
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    // ...
    this.checkToken = this.checkToken.bind(this);
    this.intervalId = null;
  }
  
  componentDidMount(){
    this.intervalId = setInterval(() => {this.checkToken()}, 10000);
  }

   checkToken() {
     console.log("token checked");      
     if (decode(localStorage.getItem('jwtToken')).exp < Date.now() / 1000) {
       this.setState({loginOpen : true}, () => {
          console.log('state updated');
          console.log(this.state.loginOpen);
          if (this.itv) {
            clearInterval(this.intervalId);
          }
      });
 }
}
```

See which approach will work better, and see if my fix works, and I can add more explanations.

One more thing I want to point out is that `clearInterval(..)` takes the ID returned from `setInterval`.

Hence the setting of `this.intervalId` and passing it to `clearInterval(..)`.

---

From your comment:

> how can I change state in parent component i.e. app component from its
>   child component. Becase login modal is in app component.

You are rendering login modal in `App` component.

You can conditionally render the login modal based on `App`'s `this.state.loginOpen`.

For example, if your `App` render function contains a login modal component called `LoginModal`

```
render() {
  <div>
    { this.state.loginOpen && <LoginModal /> }
  </div>
```

Or, if you are calling some function to show the login modal, you can do something like `if (this.state.loginOpen) { showLoginModal(); }`.

Comment: This is a great implementation to that but not useful to token generated without exp date. For example, default firebase authentication.

Comment: I am using setInterval in app.js because its the common component where all the routes are defined. So, it checks for token expire no matter in which routes it is. If I move setInterval in Authservice then setInterval own't work. I am doing this because, checking expiry time is the function of auth service. Is it possible to let setInterval in app.js and let the auth serivce do its thing like check token and open dialog if token expire?

Comment: That was why I said "`loginOpen` and `checkToken()` look like something that can be moved up to App component, and be passed to AuthService as props" in my answer. Do you think that will work?

Comment: Okey. If I moved up those function to app component. What I want to do is while making API request, if current token was expired then also I need to popup login. In that case, how can I change state in parent component i.e. app component from its child component. Becase login modal is in app component.

Comment: "I'm saying that most applications are made with many requests and if the token expires, all of them will fail together." @EricNa Do this solution solve this scenario well?

Comment: @FrancisRodrigues If the token expires, the requests should fail. If that's problematic, you should address it, but it's a separate problem from OP's issue here

Comment: Sure! I understand!